# Reading external XML via a proxy

Tags: c#, xml, proxy

I want to read some external xml, but I have to connect via a proxy, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I have the following code, the `xmlurl` contains a path to the external xml:

```
                                if (content > 0)
                            {
                                using (XmlTextReader xml = new XmlTextReader(xmlurl))
                                {
                                    while (xml.Read())
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(xml.Name);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

I had the following proxy code for another `HttpWebRequest` piece I had:

```
if(Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["behindproxy"]) == true)
                                {
                                    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
                                    Uri proxyUri = new Uri("srvisa01");
                                    proxy.Address = proxyUri;
                                    proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
                                    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxyusername"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxypassword"].ToString());
```

}

But I'm not sure this will work in this case.

Help appreciated.

Kind regards

Chris

Comment: Do you need specific credentials or would [adding proxy configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkwyc043.aspx) to your app.config be sufficent?

Comment: Specific credentials unfortunately, which makes things tricky. I did find this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720674.aspx#Y103 but I can't get the code to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to this question with some determined Googling:

```
XmlTextReader xml;
                        WebRequest web;

                        web = WebRequest.Create(xmlurl);
                        if(Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["behindproxy"].ToString()))
                        {
                            WebProxy prxy = new WebProxy();
                            Uri prxyUri = new Uri("http://xxx:8080");

                            prxy.Address = prxyUri;
                            prxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
                            prxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxyusername"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["proxypassword"].ToString());
                            web.Proxy = prxy;
                        }

                        var response = web.GetResponse().ToString();
                        xml = new XmlTextReader(response);
```

Hope this answer helps peeps :)